# How to plot high variance feature importance values generated after using logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

I want to plot feature importances generated from logistic regression using seaborn/matplotlib but the problem is that the values of features importances vary a lot.

Example- In my logistic regression model which has been build for a classification problem, the highest feature importance value is 132 whereas the feature with 2nd highest importance has a value of only 17, similarly the feature with 3rd highest importance has a value of 4.

Request you to check the code which I have used to generate feature importance & also please suggest me how can I plot feature importance values as the graph which I tried to generate is not showing the desired result.

```
code:
import math
feature_importance=pd.DataFrame(xtest.columns, columns=['feature'])
feature_importance['importance']=pow(math.e,np.array(w))
feature_importance.sort_values(by=['importance'],ascending=False).reset_index()
```

[image: Below is the screenshot of feature importance generated from LR model using above code]

```
code for generating plot:
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

sns.barplot(data=feature_importance.iloc[:7,:])
```

[image: result of code used for plotting]

Comment: You could standardize your data upstream so that the coefficients can be compared. You could also take a look at SHAP.

Comment: can you please give me precise code which will help me do it

Comment: In the link below, starsini shows a code to standardize training set and then use the training standardization on test set. You can launch this before fitting and you will see that your coefficients may be closer. Then it would be easier to plot and compare each coefficient on a same plot. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38395/standardscaler-before-or-after-splitting-data-which-is-better